# neural network in MATLAB fails in training

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pca, face-recognition

i am in the process of learning neural networks using MATLAB, i'm trying implement a face recognition program using PCA for feature extraction, and a feedforward neural network for classification.

i have 3 people in my training set, the images are stored in 'data' directory.

i am using one network for each individual, and i train each network with all the images of my training set, the code for my project is presented below:

```
dirs = dir('data');
size = numel(dirs);
eigenVecs = [];
% a neural network for each individual
net1 = feedforwardnet(10);
net2 = feedforwardnet(10);
net3 = feedforwardnet(10);

% extract eigen vectors and prepare the input of the NN
for i= 3:size
    eigenVecs{i-2} =  eigenFaces(dirs(i).name);
end
trainSet= cell2mat(eigenVecs'); % 27X1024 double

% set the target for each NN, and then train it.
T = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
train(net1, trainSet', T);
T = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
train(net2, trainSet', T);
T = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
train(net3, trainSet', T);
```

after finishing with training the network, i get this panel:

[nntraintool panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdpjF.png)

** if anyone could explain to me the progress section of the panel, because i could not understand what those numbers meant. **

after training the networks, i try to test the network using the following:

```
sim(net1, L)
```

where L is a sample from my set which is a 1X1024 vector, the result i got is this :

```
Empty matrix: 0-by-1024
```

is my approach to training the neural networks wrong ? what can i do to fix this program ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
 train(net1, trainSet', T);
```

does not save the trained network into the `net1` variable (it saves it into `ans` variable). This is the reason why the result of `sim` is empty: there is no trained network in `net1`. You have to save the trained network yourself:

```
 net1= train(net1, trainSet', T);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, that seems to fix the problem i was facing with the empty matrix, could you please elaborate for me the different parameters in the performance section of the picture i have attached ? i would love to understand those parameters. thank you

Comment: There is a description here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/train-and-apply-multilayer-neural-networks.html . Also you can refer https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainlm.html for the description of the mu parameter